# How to use conjunction in an object clause?

Tags: conjunctions, clauses

Is it OK to use comma space followed by "whereas" in an object clause like the following sentence?

> Experiments showed that H and K cells
>   were highly sensitive to sugar, whereas P cells were insensitive
>   to sugar.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you're worried about the usage 'Experiments showed that H and K cells were highly sensitive to sugar, whereas the traditional view did not accept this.' ie  '[Experiments showed that H and K cells were highly sensitive to sugar], whereas [the traditional view did not accept this.]' But your usage  '[Experiments showed that] [[H and K cells were highly sensitive to sugar], whereas [P cells were insensitive to sugar]].' is also grammatical and (more importantly) clear.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth -Yes, it looks like I need a pair of brackets in this case. I intend the scope of "that" to be everything that follows til the very end, but that commas makes the scope look ambiguous.

Comment: Pragmatics: the context dictates the scope.

Comment: Yes, it's fine...however this wouldn't be okay when the first clause already has "whereas".